# Nodejs works on local machine but on VPS it doen't

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically my nodejs/javascript code only works on my local pc, and not my vps.
I have installed all the same node_modules and all the code is the same. Heres an example of my code:

```
//Launcher.js
var foo = require("./foo.js");
var oof= new oof();
oof.foo()

//foo.js
function oof() {
this.foo = false;
}
oof.prototype.foo= function() {
this.foo = true;
}
module.exports = oof;
```

Its something like this, the error message I get is

```
TypeError: oof.foo is not a function
```

Any help would be greatly welcomed.

Comment: Your code is incorrect, it could not work anywhere. `oof` is not defined in the `Launcher.js`.

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: Yes, I can `new oof();` --- what is `oof` here? It's not declared anywhere in the code, so an exception will be thrown when you run it.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how that works on your machine, maybe I'm missing something, because the correct syntax for `Launcher.js` is:

```
var foo = require("./foo.js");
// The modules in node.js are not exported in the global namespace,
// you must reference them with the variable name you assigned them.
var oof = new foo();

oof.foo();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `foo` property is not a function so you can't call it.  You're overriding the `prototype` definition when you set `this.foo = false` in the constructor.  Now the `foo` property is just a `boolean` value so you can't call it as a function.

This JS won't work anywhere.

I'd suggest you change the name of the property where you store the `true` and `false` value so it does not conflict with the method `foo`:

```
//foo.js
function oof() {  
    this._foo = false;
}
oof.prototype.foo = function() {
    this._foo = true;
}
module.exports = oof;
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that my computer was running node version 5.10 and my vps 4, to fix this just run node -v on both computers to check if the version matches, if not update/downgrade the vps's node version so it matches your own.